# Matplotlib with Tkinter GUI - taking variable from one frame to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

Right now I want to display a matplotlib graph into a tkinter GUI, so I am following this example in https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/ . However, in this example, all the data plotted is already specified in the GraphPage class. But for my program, I need information from entries in StartPage to calculate, make fits for the data then graph it. Right now what I've tried is to put in the tk.Tk class this:

```
def get_page(self, classname):
    '''Returns an instance of a page given it's class name as a string'''
    for page in self.frames.values():
        if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
            return page
    return None
```

Then in my GraphPage add this:

```
self.controller = controller

startpage = self.controller.get_page("StartPage")

self.iso = startpage.entry1.get()
self.vol = startpage.entry2.get()
self.r = startpage.entry3.get()
self.distance = startpage.selected()
```

However what is returned to me is blank entry values from StartPage frame. How do I get the entry values from the StartPage once button on the StartPage is pushed?

Thank you!!!

EDIT: My Code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from lmfit.models import ExponentialGaussianModel
from lmfit import Parameters
from tkinter import messagebox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import loadtxt
import math

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class PeakFitting(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, GraphPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]

        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, classname):
    '''Returns an instance of a page given it's class name as a string'''
        for page in self.frames.values():
            if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
                return page
        return None

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        # Setting up frame and widget

        self.v = tk.IntVar()
        self.v.set(1)

        label_det = tk.Label(self, text="Choose Detector")
        self.mcp0 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="MCP-0", variable=self.v, value=1, command=self.selected)
        self.mcp6 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="MCP-6", variable=self.v, value=2, command=self.selected)
        self.mpet = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="MCP-MPET", variable=self.v, value=3, command=self.selected)

        label_det.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.mcp0.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
        self.mcp6.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
        self.mpet.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

        label_iso = tk.Label(self, text="Isotope A, Element (ex: 133,Cs)")
        label_vol = tk.Label(self, text="Beam Energy (eV)")
        label_range = tk.Label(self, text="Peak Data Range (ex: 1,10.5)")

        label_iso.grid(row=4, column=0)
        label_vol.grid(row=5, column=0)
        label_range.grid(row=6, column=0)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, validate="key")
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self, validate="key")
        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self, validate="key")

        self.entry1.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.entry2.grid(row=5, column=1)
        self.entry3.grid(row=6, column=1)

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GraphPage))
        button3.grid(row=7, columnspan=2)


    def selected(self):
        if self.v.get() == 1:
            self.x = 8.0
        elif self.v.get() == 2:
            self.x = 3.0
        else:
            self.x = 9.2
        return self.x

class GraphPage(StartPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        startpage = self.controller.get_page("StartPage")

        self.iso = startpage.entry1.get()
        self.vol = startpage.entry2.get()
        self.r = startpage.entry3.get()
        self.distance = startpage.selected()

        dict = {'h': 1, 'he': 2, 'li': 3, 'be': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'n': 7, 'o': 8, 'f': 9, 'ne': 10,
            'na': 11, 'mg': 12, 'al': 13, 'si': 14, 'p': 15, 's': 16, 'cl': 17, 'ar': 18,
            'k': 19, 'ca': 20, 'sc': 21, 'ti': 22, 'v': 23, 'cr': 24, 'mn': 25, 'fe': 26, 'co': 27, 'ni': 28,
            'cu': 29, 'zn': 30,
            'ga': 31, 'ge': 31, 'as': 33, 'se': 34, 'br': 35, 'kr': 36, 'rb': 37, 'sr': 38, 'y': 39,
            'zr': 40, 'nb': 41, 'mo': 42, 'tc': 43, 'ru': 44, 'rh': 45, 'pd': 46, 'ag': 47, 'cd': 48,
            'in': 49, 'sn': 50, 'sb': 51, 'te': 52, 'i': 53, 'xe': 54, 'cs': 55, 'ba': 56,
            'la': 57, 'ce': 58, 'pr': 59, 'nd': 60, 'pm': 61, 'sm': 62, 'eu': 63, 'gd': 64, 'tb': 65, 'dy': 66,
            'ho': 67, 'er': 68, 'tm': 69, 'yb': 70, 'lu': 71,
            'hf': 72, 'ta': 73, 'w': 74, 're': 75, 'os': 76, 'ir': 77, 'pt': 78, 'au': 79, 'hg': 80, 'tl': 81,
            'pb': 82, 'bi': 83, 'po': 84, 'at': 85, 'rn': 86,
            'fr': 87, 'ra': 88, 'ac': 89, 'th': 90, 'pa': 91, 'u': 92, 'np': 93, 'pu': 94, 'am': 95, 'cm': 96,
            'bk': 97, 'cf': 98, 'es': 99, 'fm': 100, 'md': 101, 'no': 102, 'lr': 103,
            'rf': 104, 'db': 105, 'sg': 106, 'bh': 107, 'hs': 108, 'mt': 109, 'ds': 110, 'rg': 111, 'cn': 112,
            'uut': 113, 'fl': 114, 'uup': 115, 'lv': 116, 'uus': 117, 'uuo': 118}

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button1.grid()

        if self.r == "" or self.iso == "" or self.vol == "":
             return None

        r = self.r
        tup = tuple(int(x) for x in r.split(","))

        iso = self.iso.get()
        iso_list = []
        for e in iso.split(","):
            iso_list.append(e)

        if len(tup) == 2:
            if tup[0] > tup[1]:
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Input data range must be from lower to higher time")
                return None

        f = open("mass.mas12.txt", "r")
        i = 0
        while (i < 40):
            header = f.readline()
            i += 1
        self.mass = 0

        # iterate through text file

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            if (list[0] == columns[3]):
                if (list[1].lower() == columns[4].lower()):
                    if (len(columns) == 15):
                        self.mass = float(columns[12].replace("#", "")) + float(columns[13].replace("#", "")) / 10e6
                    else:
                        self.mass = float(columns[11].replace("#", "")) + float(columns[12].replace("#", "")) / 10e6

                    # Calculation

        list = []
        valid = {}
        for q in range(1, 119):
            if q < dict[iso_list[1].lower()]:
                time = (self.distance * math.sqrt(self.mass * 1.6605402e-27 / (2 * q * 1.6022e-19 * float(self.vol)))) * 10e6
                if (time >= float(tup[0])) & (time <= float(tup[1])):
                    list.append(time)
                    valid[time] = q

            # check if charge states of valid time is available for isotope

        if len(valid) == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Change states in range do not exist for given element")
            return None

            # Fit:
            # Query data -> get x, y values... somehow
        data = loadtxt('20160418_1532_scan_1594_step_1_cup_in.csv')
        x = data[:, 0]
        y = data[:, 3]

        mod = None
        p = Parameters()
        i = 0

        for time in list:
            if mod == None:
                mod = ExponentialGaussianModel(prefix='gaussian' + str(i) + '_')
                p.add_many(('gaussian' + str(i) + '_center', time, True, time - 2, time + 2),
                       ('gaussian' + str(i) + '_sigma', 0.15, True, 0),
                       ('gaussian' + str(i) + '_gamma', 0.95, True, 0, 1),
                       ('gaussian' + str(i) + '_amplitude', 50, True, 10))
            else:
                mod = mod + ExponentialGaussianModel(prefix='gaussian' + str(i) + '_')
                p.add_many(('gaussian' + str(i) + '_center', time, True, time - 2, time + 2),
                       ('gaussian' + str(i) + '_sigma', 0.15, True, 0),
                       ('gaussian' + str(i) + '_gamma', 0.95, True, 0, 1),
                       ('gaussian' + str(i) + '_amplitude', 50, True, 10))
            i = i + 1

        out = mod.fit(y, p, x=x)
        fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        a = fig.add_subplot()
        a.plot(x, y)
        a.plot(x, out.best_fit, 'r-')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)




app = PeakFitting()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would have thought you would have a StartPage class with methods to return the parameter(s), and the have the GraphPage class query that class (not page) for them...

Comment: @JonCuster I could be wrong, but it seems that the program runs everything through before rendering, hence GraphPage frame has already been made before there's any input for entries in StartPage, and the show_frame method just shows that already made frame. So even if I query StartPage from the beginning, I'll still get blank values, not the actually entries. I need to have a way to let GraphPage update its values and frame result, but I don't know how :(

Comment: Well, that is a problem with how you are structuring things! You are tying your 'pages' and your 'code' too closely together. Separate your display code from your data processing code.

Comment: @JonCuster Can you extend on that please? How could I make sure the graphPage is only run after the entries from StartPage has been input?

Comment: You should be thinking of having classes to _display_ information (show pretty graphs), and classes to _handle_ the information (do whatever calculations). Your display classes can show an empty graph on initialization. As information is processed, you use the display classes to present it to the user. The display classes should not, themselves, do anything to the data.

Comment: To delay action after user input, you have to **bind** to an **event**, thus you willl have code executing after the user input. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm for detailed explanation.  In you case a button might suffice ( http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#patterns ).

Comment: @JonCuster  Thank you for your comment! I do see now that all of my calculation is in GraphPage (as seen in my code I include), which is wrong. However, I don't quite know how to separate the calculating and displaying classes and link them together... Can you give me some suggestions? (I'm very new to python and tkinter/matplotlib, so your help would be greatly appreciated!!!)